# What is a good way to load certain class(es) automatically on every controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, autoload

What would be a good way of having some classes auto loaded on all controllers in my MVC framework?

I need to check on every page if a user is logged in or not so I can proceed the code accordingly, and a menu helper that returns the dynamically built navigation (array) for that controller.

I would just do it in the parent controller constructor so every class that extends it will inherit them automatically.

```
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $request;
    protected $user;
    protected $menu;

    public function __construct(Request $request, User $user, MenuHelper $menu)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->user    = $user;
        $this->menu    = $menu;
    }

    protected abstract function index();
}
```

But is this a good way to do? I know this is dependency injection, but what if my class would need any additional classes? Would I have to set those in the child controller constructor through dependency injection?

If so, that means my router would have to hold a list of every controller and dependency objects to know the appropriate amount and order of objects to inject in each specific controller.

Right now I'm just calling **every** controller in my router like the following:

```
$controller = new $controller();

$controller->$action($params);
```

Comment: One thin I cannot understand is: why you are exposing a [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) (the user, which should be inside model layer) and a [presentation object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) (the menu, which should be in the view)  to the controller?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I have done some research on what an MVC  structure in PHP really is and to a certain extent it's the same concept to everyone, but I also noticed that everyone is very opinionated about it after that. Some say Views should have no PHP, some say it's fine to have some conditional statements in there, some say that they use the controller to control **everything**. Also, my user class *is* inside my model layer, but if it's not right to inject it, then how would you instantiated classes from the model layer so you can interact with them in your controller?

Comment: Please stop confusing "views" and "templates". And controller has one specific responsibility: altering the state of other parts in MVC triad (usually only the model layer). And domain objects should not leak to the presentation layer. The presentation layer should be interacting with model layer through services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is this a good way to do? I know this is dependency injection, but
>   what if my class would need any additional classes? Would I have to
>   set those in the child controller constructor through dependency
>   injection?

It's a good way to go if you need the benefits associated with dependency injection, because you clearly are taking up some overhead in going that way.

If you acquire additional dependencies later on then yes, you will have to change your base and/or derived constructors appropriately.

> If so, that means my router would have to hold a list of every
>   controller and dependency objects to know the appropriate amount and
>   order of objects to inject in each specific controller.

That's the straightforward conclusion, but it would violate DRY and obviously be a sore point in your design. That's why when you go this route it's almost a given that you will utilize a DI container (e.g. [illuminate/container](https://github.com/illuminate/container)) to automatically resolve the dependencies and instantiate your classes like this:

```
$controller = $container->make($controller);
```

The container will look up the class, determine its dependencies, resolve them recursively, and instantiate the object you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, but what do you mean by overhead?

Comment: @502Error: I left that deliberately vague. In your description the "overhead" would be clerical: you need to know what dependencies each controller has, instantiate them one by one, pass them to the constructor -- and if the dependencies change, you have to amend the code accordingly. When moving to a container this overhead is exchanged for runtime costs (reflection on the controller class, etc). My point is that it's good if you need it or expect to do so; but it's just wasted effort if (obv unrealistic example) the app is a trivial 5-min proof of concept.